# append and remove div using jquery when select n number of options

Tags: jquery

i want to add n number of input field groups when select n number of options in select box. i am able to append successfully using jquery in a div but when i reduce n numbers in select box, it wipes all the data filled in other field groups.

overall what i need is when i select 5 then 5 times it should append the field group and after this when we select 4 then last appended div should be removed and if there is data filled in other divs it should remain there.

how to do this

```
<select name="adults" id="adults" class="shadow">
 <option value="1">1 adult</option>
  <option value="2">2 adults</option>
 <option value="3">3 adults</option>
  <option value="4">4 adults</option>
 <option value="5">5 adults</option>
 </select>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
        var content = $("#content");
        $("#adults").change(function() {
            newContent = "";
            for (var i = 2; i <= noofadult; i++) {
                newContent += '<div class="o-accent-box u-clearfix u-margin-bottom-medium passenger-detail"><h3 class="h5-like o-heading-icon icon-passenger">Passenger ' + i + ' (Adult)<span class="field-required">*</span></h3><div class="o-form-item form-item-title"><label for="title-select-{index}" class="u-visually-hidden">Title</label><select id="title-select-{index}" name="visitor[' + i + '][title]" required="" class="o-form-item__txt-input"><option value="">Title</option><option value="Mr">Mr</option><option value="Mrs">Mrs</option><option value="Ms">Ms</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Dr">Dr</option></select></div><div class="o-form-item form-item-first-name"><label for="pax-first-name-0" class="u-visually-hidden">First Name</label><input id="pax-first-name-0" type="text" placeholder="First name(s)" name="visitor[' + i + '][firstName]" class="o-form-item__txt-input"></div><div class="o-form-item form-item-surname"><label for="pax-surname-0" class="u-visually-hidden">Surname(s)</label><input id="pax-surname-0" type="text" placeholder="Surname(s)" name="visitor[' + i + '][lastName]" class="o-form-item__txt-input"></div></div>';


            }

            content.html(newContent);

        }).trigger('change');;

    </script>
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to keep the inputs in the dom and hide/show and enable/disable them instead of building the html in the change handler

Comment: but this select option is dynamic, n number of option is based on the seats left in a group of travellers.

Comment: Fine....hide/show based on number selected. Then any user input won't be affected

Comment: there can be 25 person group also, what to do in such case. it looks practical when we have 4-5.

Comment: You can dynamically create all that html when page loads then

Comment: can you help me with some codes. i am just not able to understand it.